# Binary Rejected : Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the Compnay brand

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

On new version suddenly apple not publishing my updates on app
 below is message from apple

The seller and company names associated with your app still do not reflect the name, “AirmedLabs,” in the app or its metadata, as required by section 1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

Next Steps

Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the AirmedLabs brand. If you have developed these apps on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account.
We are unable to proceed with the review of your app until this issue has been addressed. Best regards,

here is current live version of app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airmedlabs/id1152367695?mt=8

Comment: Probably you need to contact Apple first, provide the info that company agree to use your developer account to publish, if it doesnt work then will have to create new developer account and transfer the app there

Comment: Apple is tightening its review policies. Apps that are published under a company brand must be published under that company's developer registration. Even if this is "your" company, you must pay for an organisational membership rather than a personal membership.

Comment: The app is already live. we have put updates may time.

Comment: What has been approved doesn't matter unfortunately. It is what they will approve *now*

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same issue. They accepted once I changed the **individual membership account to a company/Organisation membership** & uploaded it again. If your product is a registered brand, it should be a company account which reflects the brand name of your product.
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. I changed the name of the application but they rejected it again. I tried to upgrade to Company membership and I got this message "This organization could not be verified as a legal entity. If you are a sole proprietorship/single person company, enroll as an individual. If this organization should be listed as a legal entity,"
Please any help? I have been struggling for three months

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem and have appealed the Review Team but haven't get any clear response about that 1.2 point. I thought it has to be with web-shops embedded in web views, but I couldn't confirm it as there is no a regular pattern of rejection.